# can radical and rational equations be linear?

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra

I am a student and I am just started the title of linear equations. I want to learn about linear equations deeply and linear equations make me confused. I have some question to ask you that explain to me and remove my confusion.

1. The book said that we call for those equations linear that have first degree power or general forms of linear equations now my question is that we call for those kind of equations linear that have general form of linear equation or can change to general form or other forms of linear equations form example can we call $10/x=5$ linear or square root of $(y-9)=10$ linear?
2. Can those rational and radical equations that can be manipulated to linear forms called linear equations like the examples above?
3. Are all first degree one variable equations linear?

oh sorry for long paragraph but can't explain my questions in short paragraphs.
thank you

Comment: Your text would be a lot easier to read if you used more punctuation marks.

Comment: Apparently you can explain your questions in short paragraphs

Answer (score 2):

To define linear equations, we need to understand linear functions of a variable. Let us assume a function $f:R\to R$, such that

$$f(ax_1 + bx_2) = af(x_1) + bf(x_2)$$

For all $x_1,x_2,a,b \in R$

Any function with this property is a **linear function**. Now, we can define a linear equation to be
$$f(x) = 0$$

where $f$ is a linear function in $x$.

Now, when you look at functions like $$f(x) = \frac{10}{x}-5$$

This is clearly  not a linear function, and hence the equation $f(x) = 0$ per se is not a linear equation, but with a bit of manipulation, we can define a $g(x) = 10-5x$, such that the following is true

$$\text{if x solves g(x) = 0} \implies \text{x solves f(x) = 0}$$

And hence the equations that you have mentioned though are not linear, they are analogous to a linear equation, and hence they share the same **solution set**. This gives us a tool to solve a non-linear equation using a corresponding transformation to get a linear equation, which is easier to solve

Comment: sir you mean that the graph of  these equations are not linear?

Comment: You cannot graph an equation, you graph a function.

Answer (score 1):

The equation $y+x+10=0$ is a linear equation.

The equation $y^2+x^2+2xy+20y+20x+100=0$ is not a linear equation, even though its solutions lie on the same straight line as the first example.

In a similar sense, your $\frac{10}{x}=5$ and $\sqrt{y-9}=10$ are not linear equations even though they are equivalent to $5x-10=0$ and $y-109=0$, which are linear equations

Comment: it mean that we just change non linear equations to linear just to solve non linear equations easily

Comment: @mayar - the very similar $y^2+x^2+2xy+20y+19x+100=0$ is not a straight line so you cannot always  just change non-linear equations to linear to solve non-linear equations easily